# (Ubuntu 16.04) Issues with wireless connection

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, network-manager

Today I made a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 on another computer. I have two issues related to wi-fi connection:

1. When I turn on (or restart) the computer it appears a message that confirm that I'm connected to the wi-fi connection. But it seems that the connection last about 30 seconds (I can start a google search but then I not able to access any other page or refresh the search page). In few words, it seems that I have wi-fi connection but no internet connection.
2. I have tried a solution that stated that restarting the network manager (e.g. `sudo service network-manager restart`) would work. When I try this, Ubuntu is not able to restablish the wi-fi connection at all.

The output for `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` is the following:

```
 07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192E/RTL8192SE Wireless LAN Controller [10ec:8192] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192E/RTL8192SE Wireless LAN Controller [10ec:8182]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl819xE
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas to fix this. Have a good day.

---

**EDIT 1**

@waltinator:

Hi, thanks for the reply.

`iwconfig` gave me this information:

```
enp7s0    802.11bgn  ESSID:"INFINITUM5208"  Nickname:"rtl8192E"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.417 GHz  Access Point: A8:D3:F7:7B:1D:2E   
          Bit Rate=26 Mb/s   
          Retry min limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management period:0us  mode:All packets received
          Link Quality=69/100  Signal level=-53 dBm  Noise level=-104 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.
```

`zgrep wlan0 /var/log/kern.log` gave me this information:

```
Aug  4 18:21:26 ariel-Satellite-M505D kernel: [   15.175287] rtl819xE 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: renamed from wlan0
Aug  4 18:50:33 ariel-Satellite-M505D kernel: [   16.848585] rtl819xE 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: renamed from wlan0
Aug  4 19:08:58 ariel-Satellite-M505D kernel: [   19.039981] rtl819xE 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: renamed from wlan0
Aug  4 19:15:41 ariel-Satellite-M505D kernel: [   17.211518] rtl819xE 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: renamed from wlan0
Aug  4 19:22:42 ariel-Satellite-M505D kernel: [   17.386107] rtl819xE 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: renamed from wlan0
Aug  4 20:11:21 ariel-Satellite-M505D kernel: [   15.675030] rtl819xE 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: renamed from wlan0
Aug  4 20:17:12 ariel-Satellite-M505D kernel: [   19.612186] rtl819xE 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: renamed from wlan0
```

When I tried to execute `linux-image-extras-$(uname -r)` I got an error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-extras-4.4.0-31-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-image-extras-4.4.0-31-generic'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-extras-4.4.0-31-generic'
```

---

**EDIT 2**

@Lucas Czepaniki:

Hi, thanks for the reply.

I tried both commands (using ethernet as you suggested) and then rebooted, but it seems the issue is not fixed.

Comment: More commands to run and Edit in to your Q: `iwconfig`, and notice your device name, `wlan0` for the following example `zgrep wlan0 /var/log/kern.log`. Have you installed the `linux-image-extras-$(uname -r)` package? Have you searched AskUbuntu for `RTL8192E`?   See the box in top right of the AskUbuntu page.

Comment: Have you tried disabling Secure boot? Assumeing you updated you operating system, sometimes secure boot can cause problems.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. How do I disable Secure boot? I did not update the OS, I installed Ubuntu 16.04 directly to the computer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem with Ubuntu 14.04, I wasn't able to connect to any wi-fi network.
Have you tried updating the driver?

If not, try to run the following command while connected with ethernet:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

After the installation is finished, you should be able to connect and test if its working.